# Azure Service Bus | Partitioned Queue

Tags: c#, azure, partitioning, azure-servicebus-queues

I am running demo from [Github](https://github.com/Azure/azure-service-bus/tree/master/samples/DotNet/Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging/PartitionedQueues) on Azure Service Bus Partitioned Queues. I understand that partition queue broker will store the messages with same partition-id in order (*I mean, sequence number would be continuous despite the order of insertion of messages in queue*).

Now, I witness a strange scenario that messages with different partition-id like 'F' & 'H' are in the same sequence range.

Could you please clarify these anomalies with Service Bus Broker Behavior?

Comment: What do you mean partition ID "F" and "H"? Partition **Key**, if not specified is calculated base on `MessageId` or `SessionId`. Messages sent within the same transaction will all end up having the same Partition Key as well.

Comment: @sean-felman, Partition Keys are F & H. We explicitly sent one letter partition keys to Partitioned Queue. Somehow F & H were put in the consecutive order. Other alphabets are partitioned fine so far. I wonder why it grouped F & H into a partition.

Comment: Whatever the algorithm the broker is using has resulting in such distribution I assume.

Comment: Yes, I tried with 2 lettered partition-keys. Now, partitioning looks fine with 2 letter keys.

Comment: Heading a single letter partition key is not a real world scenario anyways. This is why having a GUID would probably be better for randomization. Or a message ID using GUID.